# Create a chart/table from nested data in splunk

Tags: json, splunk, splunk-query

I have some metrics/logs being shipped to Splunk. It's a nested event. Here's an example.

```
{ [-]
   AppID: 209
   Created: 2022-02-08T22:47:54.695231Z
   Environment: test
   ID: 224becc49ca3
   Level: info
   Message: Kafka Stats
   Properties: { [-]
     CallerInfo: /src/src/Workers/EventsListenerWorker.cs:ReceiverOnStatsEmitted(77)
     stats: { "name": "kafka#consumer-1", "client_id": "kafka", "type": "consumer", "ts":3075091267661, "time":1644360474, "age":1826426664461, "replyq":0, "msg_cnt":0, "msg_size":0, "msg_max":0, "msg_size_max":0, "simple_cnt":0, "metadata_cache_cnt":1, "topics":{ "right-to-delete-request": { "topic":"right-to-delete-request", "age":1826426483, "metadata_age":26162, "batchsize": { "min":0, "max":0, "avg":0, "sum":0, "stddev": 0, "p50": 0, "p75": 0, "p90": 0, "p95": 0, "p99": 0, "p99_99": 0, "outofrange": 0, "hdrsize": 14448, "cnt":0 }, "batchcnt": { "min":0, "max":0, "avg":0, "sum":0, "stddev": 0, "p50": 0, "p75": 0, "p90": 0, "p95": 0, "p99": 0, "p99_99": 0, "outofrange": 0, "hdrsize": 8304, "cnt":0 }, "partitions":{ "0": { "partition":0, "broker":0, "leader":0, "desired":true, "unknown":false, "msgq_cnt":0, "msgq_bytes":0, "xmit_msgq_cnt":0, "xmit_msgq_bytes":0, "fetchq_cnt":0, "fetchq_size":0, "fetch_state":"active", "query_offset":-1001, "next_offset":13, "app_offset":13, "stored_offset":13, "commited_offset":13, "committed_offset":13, "eof_offset":13, "lo_offset":10, "hi_offset":13, "ls_offset":13, "consumer_lag":0, "consumer_lag_stored":0, "txmsgs":0, "txbytes":0, "rxmsgs":4, "rxbytes":2734, "msgs": 4, "rx_ver_drops": 0, "msgs_inflight": 0, "next_ack_seq": 0, "next_err_seq": 0, "acked_msgid": 0} , "1": { "partition":1, "broker":3, "leader":3, "desired":true, "unknown":false, "msgq_cnt":0, "msgq_bytes":0, "xmit_msgq_cnt":0, "xmit_msgq_bytes":0, "fetchq_cnt":0, "fetchq_size":0, "fetch_state":"active", "query_offset":-1001, "next_offset":16, "app_offset":16, "stored_offset":16, "commited_offset":16, "committed_offset":16, "eof_offset":16, "lo_offset":13, "hi_offset":16, "ls_offset":16, "consumer_lag":0, "consumer_lag_stored":0, "txmsgs":0, "txbytes":0, "rxmsgs":3, "rxbytes":2058, "msgs": 3, "rx_ver_drops": 0, "msgs_inflight": 0, "next_ack_seq": 0, "next_err_seq": 0, "acked_msgid": 0} , "2": { "partition":2, "broker":1, "leader":1, "desired":true, "unknown":false, "msgq_cnt":0, "msgq_bytes":0, "xmit_msgq_cnt":0, "xmit_msgq_bytes":0, "fetchq_cnt":0, "fetchq_size":0, "fetch_state":"active", "query_offset":-1001, "next_offset":7, "app_offset":7, "stored_offset":7, "commited_offset":7, "committed_offset":7, "eof_offset":7, "lo_offset":3, "hi_offset":7, "ls_offset":7, "consumer_lag":0, "consumer_lag_stored":0, "txmsgs":0, "txbytes":0, "rxmsgs":4, "rxbytes":2744, "msgs": 4, "rx_ver_drops": 0, "msgs_inflight": 0, "next_ack_seq": 0, "next_err_seq": 0, "acked_msgid": 0} , "3": { "partition":3, "broker":2, "leader":2, "desired":true, "unknown":false, "msgq_cnt":0, "msgq_bytes":0, "xmit_msgq_cnt":0, "xmit_msgq_bytes":0, "fetchq_cnt":0, "fetchq_size":0, "fetch_state":"active", "query_offset":-1001, "next_offset":14, "app_offset":14, "stored_offset":14, "commited_offset":14, "committed_offset":14, "eof_offset":14, "lo_offset":10, "hi_offset":14, "ls_offset":14, "consumer_lag":0, "consumer_lag_stored":0, "txmsgs":0, "txbytes":0, "rxmsgs":5, "rxbytes":3421, "msgs": 5, "rx_ver_drops": 0, "msgs_inflight": 0, "next_ack_seq": 0, "next_err_seq": 0, "acked_msgid": 0} , "4": { "partition":4, "broker":0, "leader":0, "desired":true, "unknown":false, "msgq_cnt":0, "msgq_bytes":0, "xmit_msgq_cnt":0, "xmit_msgq_bytes":0, "fetchq_cnt":0, "fetchq_size":0, "fetch_state":"active", "query_offset":-1001, "next_offset":10, "app_offset":10, "stored_offset":10, "commited_offset":10, "committed_offset":10, "eof_offset":10, "lo_offset":7, "hi_offset":10, "ls_offset":10, "consumer_lag":0, "consumer_lag_stored":0, "txmsgs":0, "txbytes":0, "rxmsgs":3, "rxbytes":2057, "msgs": 3, "rx_ver_drops": 0, "msgs_inflight": 0, "next_ack_seq": 0, "next_err_seq": 0, "acked_msgid": 0} , "5": { "partition":5, "broker":3, "leader":3, "desired":true, "unknown":false, "msgq_cnt":0, "msgq_bytes":0, "xmit_msgq_cnt":0, "xmit_msgq_bytes":0, "fetchq_cnt":0, "fetchq_size":0, "fetch_state":"active", "query_offset":-1001, "next_offset":9, "app_offset":9, "stored_offset":9, "commited_offset":9, "committed_offset":9, "eof_offset":9, "lo_offset":8, "hi_offset":9, "ls_offset":9, "consumer_lag":0, "consumer_lag_stored":0, "txmsgs":0, "txbytes":0, "rxmsgs":1, "rxbytes":685, "msgs": 1, "rx_ver_drops": 0, "msgs_inflight": 0, "next_ack_seq": 0, "next_err_seq": 0, "acked_msgid": 0} , "-1": { "partition":-1, "broker":-1, "leader":-1, "desired":false, "unknown":false, "msgq_cnt":0, "msgq_bytes":0, "xmit_msgq_cnt":0, "xmit_msgq_bytes":0, "fetchq_cnt":0, "fetchq_size":0, "fetch_state":"none", "query_offset":-1001, "next_offset":0, "app_offset":-1001, "stored_offset":-1001, "commited_offset":-1001, "committed_offset":-1001, "eof_offset":-1001, "lo_offset":-1001, "hi_offset":-1001, "ls_offset":-1001, "consumer_lag":-1, "consumer_lag_stored":-1, "txmsgs":0, "txbytes":0, "rxmsgs":0, "rxbytes":0, "msgs": 0, "rx_ver_drops": 0, "msgs_inflight": 0, "next_ack_seq": 0, "next_err_seq": 0, "acked_msgid": 0} } } } , "cgrp": { "state": "up", "stateage": 98426097, "join_state": "steady", "rebalance_age": 1826426483, "rebalance_cnt": 1, "rebalance_reason": "Metadata for subscribed topic(s) has changed", "assignment_size": 6 }, "tx":15196172, "tx_bytes":2367935320, "rx":15196154, "rx_bytes":2126440118, "txmsgs":0, "txmsg_bytes":0, "rxmsgs":20, "rxmsg_bytes":13699}
   }
   ServerHostname: bd8c0
   ServerIP: 1.2.3.4
   UserName: root
}
```

I want to create either a table or a chart based on the data in the stats field.
So something like

```
TopicName                 Partition consumer_lag
right-to-delete-request   1         0
                          2         0
etc
```

I tried this `spath output=consumerlag path=Properties.stats.topics{}.partitions{}.consumer_lag | table *` to see if I can atleast get the consumer_lag but that did not work.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with spath.  If I feed it a path - any path - it produces nothing.  But if I don't give it a path and it makes a fiedl for every item in the json then it works fine.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah When you say every item in the json, do you mean in the stats under Properties? I was tabulate with selected values that are enclosed in the stats {}

Comment: Here is something I came up with: that works if your search produces only one event https://pastebin.com/vGhU9Fyq Perhaps you might be able to tailor it to do what you want.